# dynamically created element when mouse in. (trigger the mouse out event unexpectedly)

Tags: jquery

I want to have toolbar, where mouse-out/in events are detected from divs that have the class `container`. The `mouseover` and `mouseout`events are working as expected. These events are triggered when the mouse moves in and out of elements AND it's descendants. But there is something not to be expected happened: The newly created div is removed when the mouse was moved on itself.and after removed it will trigger the `mouseover` event, So another new div is created.This makes it Dazzling. Anyone who ever encountered this kind of problem please help me. thanks.

Say you have this HTML:

```
<div id='parent' class="parent container">
    <div id="child1" class="child container">
    </div>
    <div id="child2" class="child container">
    </div>
</div>
```

And, this JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('div.container').on('mouseover', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).append("<div class='newdiv'></div>")
        console.log("into " +$(this).attr('id'));
    }).on('mouseout', function(e){
        $(".newdiv",this).remove();
        console.log("out from  " + $(this).attr('id'));
    })
});
```

With CSS:

```
.parent
{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
}

.child
{
    float:left;
    width:40%;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:1px;
    height:300px;
}

.newdiv{
    border:1px solid blue;
    margin:2px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All, I do find a way to make it , but it is very verbose and looks urgly...Could anyone can give a better way to make it easier and fun.. hopefully. thanks.

```
$(function() {
    $('div.container').mouseenter(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).css("border","2px solid red");
        $(this).append("<div class='newdiv'></div>"); 
        $(this).parents().each(function(){
            if ($(this).children(".newdiv").length>0)
            {
                $(this).children(".newdiv").remove();
                $(this).css("border","1px solid red");
            }
        });
        if ($(".newdiv",this).length==0)
         {
            //alert('ddd');

         }

        console.log("into " +$(this).attr('id'));
    }).mouseleave( function(e){
        $(".newdiv",this).remove();
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass("container") && $(".newdiv",$(this).parent()).length==0)
        {
            $(this).parent().css("border","2px solid red");
            $(this).parent().append("<div class='newdiv'></div>"); 
        }

        $(this).css("border","1px solid red");
        console.log("out from  " + $(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, it was in your CSS. Add the position relative. otherwise it assumes the one first one with the position relative.

```
.child
{
    float:left;
    width:40%;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:1px;
    height:300px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/Jn7e2/

Ow and you do not have a semicolon behind the append function.
That would overcome any other problems.

Comment: Hi, Friend ,You didn't get what I said. please try to move the mouse on the new created div . thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to use show() and hide() to focus the divs, since there might be a problem with events propagating from child to parent. What about this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Jn7e2/1/

```
<div id='parent' class="parent container">
    <div id="child1" class="child container">
        <div class="newdiv" style="display:none">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="child2" class="child container">
        <div class="newdiv" style="display:none">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

- JS:

```
    $(function() {
      $('div.container').on('mouseover', function(e){

      e.stopPropagation();
          $(this).children(".newdiv").show();
          console.log("into " +$(this).attr('id'));
       }).on('mouseout', function(e){
           e.stopPropagation();
           $(".newdiv",this).hide();
           console.log("out from  " + $(this).attr('id'));
       })
     });
```

Comment: Yeah. @poseid, This is what I done before .I don't want to use this way , because it will be many `.newdiv` in the DOM, It is against DRY . It will be not fun with code .. thanks.

Comment: So I just create a `.newdiv` when `moveover`, There would be only one `.newdiv` at any time.thanks.