# Mouseenter and MouseLeave trigger at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know the usage of `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. Below is my code sample:

```
$('div').mouseenter(function(e){
   ...
}).mouseleave( function(e){
   ...
   //let say it will take 5 second. 
});
```

But my question is, is it possible that two handlers are triggered at the same time if I move the mouse quickly? I mean `mouseleave` doesn't finish , meanwhile `mouseenter` is triggered because the mouse just moved in.

**Updated**

In my example, what I mean is if the mouse move in 3 seconds after `mouseleave` has been triggered, will it also trigger `mouseenter`? If it does, does it mean the same DOM element trigger `mouseenter` and leave at the same time? Thanks.

Comment: Not possible to trigger them at **the exact same** time, but it is not unusual at all that the events that follow the trigger could overlap.

Comment: If events are indeed firing quickly that it is making it look concurrent. I would advice you to use - `hover()`. Read - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663818/element-fades-in-out-more-than-once-on-mouseover/15664084#15664084

Comment: `hover` is not what I want . thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to trigger both event at the same time. As javasript is not multi-threaded. If you want to put some delay between execution you can use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I mean It will make the code not easy to be readable and to be debugged. please review my another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614975/dynamically-created-element-when-mouse-in-trigger-the-mouse-out-event-unexpect,I post the answer myself in it, In my code I found sometimes the dynamically-created element wasn't removed.especially when I move the mouse quickly in the page. So I thought the reason would be that mouseenter and mouseleave were triggered at the same time. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

no ....there is no possibbilities of calling both the function at same time.... and you can't be quick enough for that

Comment: >> I mean the mouseleave doesn't finish , meanwhile the mouseenter is triggered!<<

He means the ensuing events stack.

Comment: well... in that case your above code will work... `hover()` is shorthand for this event but does the same thing.... you want the mouseenter to be called after few second once the mouse leave and enters again ???

Comment: yes .Let's say the mouse leave handle will takes 5 seconds, in this period of time (5 sec). mouse enter again .